# Insert citation's author without natbib nor biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to insert the authors of a citation, i.e. something like natbib's `\citeauthor`.
I have to use a given bibliography style (`.bst`), but this bib style does not support `natbib` and biblatex does not support `.bst` files. So far, I determined to write the author's name manually in the text.

Is there any alternative?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{sigchi} % The class I need. 
\usepackage{color} % Dependency of the class I need.

\usepackage{cite} % Replacing this by natbib fails.

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{the-citation} have done great things~\cite{the-citation}.
% Obviously fails: \citeauthor is not defined.


\bibliographystyle{SIGCHI-Reference-Format} % The reference format I need.
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

In case it can be useful, [here is the document class](https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/blob/8494979272ccc3c44960f042ee3ccab6a01c1eb5/LaTeX/sigchi.cls) I am using and [here is the bibliography style](https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/blob/8494979272ccc3c44960f042ee3ccab6a01c1eb5/LaTeX/SIGCHI-Reference-Format.bst) I am using (though I think it is way easier to assume that `biblatex` and `natbib` are unavailable than trying to dig into this template).

Comment: You can make life easier for potential answers if you provide a MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/36296

Comment: Right, I added one.

Comment: These files do not provide such a facility.